# Store Values in a Database or Hardcode them

Tags: database, coding-style

I have a general programming question I’m sure you all have been confronted with at some point. I am working on an app for iPhone/iPad, although this isn’t really an iOS or Objective C question, that needs a few values for identifying and describing certain aspects of the application. For example, I might have shirts for sale as small, medium and large. Should these values just be enumerated in hard code inside of the application or is it better to put them into a database and use a relationship to the other database properties.

PS I’m not selling shirts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience I classify data into three areas:

1. Hard code a value/make an enumeration etc.
2. Put a value in a configuration file.
3. Put data in the database.

If I think a value is going to never change (if it's an array, never have a value added), then I'm ok hard coding it.

If a value will need to be changed often - or I'd like to change it without recompiling - *and* it's a single value, then I'll put it in a config.

If the data has the potential to change a lot *and* grow (more and more values added), then I'll put it in a database.

Most of my decisions are driven by laziness. You need to think about the future and what will be the easiest thing to maintain.

As you said though, if the data is needed by other queries in your database, then put it in the database.

No matter what, make sure you have the data in one place.  Don't put a value in a config file *and* the database.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I was thinking along the same lines. My thought process was heading down the following path: If I need or want the user to have the ability to add to the list then put it in the database. Else, I’ll just hard code it knowing that if I need the data updated I’ll have to resubmit the app - but that would have to be the case either way.

However, I have decided to go ahead and add the list values to the database. This way, the other objects can have a reference to them and if I ever want the user to add to the list themselves it’ll be in the database.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds good to me.  You seem to have thought it through.  I know I just hate writing boilerplate database access code and avoid it if I can. =) If you don't mind doing that, the database is a fine place.

Answer (score 2):

I guess putting them in database would be convenient since it will be easier for you to update the lists in the future.